# Devextreme datagrid infinite scrolling sending wrong page size in CustomStore loadOptions

Tags: datagrid, infinite-scroll, devextreme-angular

I have a devextreme datagrid in which I have applied infinite scrolling and loading data from server.

Everything is working fine.
The data is loading from server on scrolling.

The only weird problem I am facing is that in every alternate scroll the the `loadOptions.take` is doubling.

So for example if I set the page size to 100, then on first scroll the value of `loadOptions.take` will be 100, which is correct but on the second scroll its value will come as 200, then again 100 and so... on...

This is happening for any page size I put, so if I put page size 50, the value will come like 50, then 100, then 50 again and so on.

This is breaking my logic of `pageNumber` calculation.

The `loadOptions.take` which is actually the page size should always be same which I set in paging setting.

Is this how the infinite scrolling is designed or what could be going wrong?